# Using a DAW as a pure multi-channel playback device

Tags: midi, daw

I have a question about using DAWS as midi players.

I want to use the instruments available in Logic Pro X or Ableton
to play a stream of midi events.

As a simple example I'd like to assign midi channel 1
to a piano and channel 2 to strings.

Then I want to sent midi events

```
noteOn channel1 noteNumber Vol1
noteOn channel2 noteNumber2 Vol2
```

From some external software what I'm writing.

The problem I's facing is that in Logic Pro X I can only receive and
play midi events from an external source if I arm the channel by
setting it in record mode, and I can only do this on a single track.

If I arm the piano track I only hear the channel 1 events - if I arm
the strings track I only hear the strings - but I want to hear both
(they are on different midi channels so this shoudl be possible).

I don't really want to record anything just hear sounds when midi
events are received. But I have to record on a specific track (1 or 2)
but cannot arrange playback on multiple tracks.

What I want to tell Logic Pro X is something like this:

```
listen for midi events on channel 1 and play with
software instrument 1

listen for midi events on channel 2 and play with
software instrument 2
```

I'm not interested in recording anything - just hearing sounds

I've tried with both Logic Pro X and Ableton but both appear to work
in the same way - they seem to assume that external midi events
can be recorded only on a single channel only ...

Is there anyway to do what I want???

Comment: Not posting this as an answer yet, as I don't know if this is specifically possible in Logic, but it was certainly a Midi sequencer staple function for many years... set the input & output channels to **any** [or 0 if it doesn't show 'any'] This should give a 'straight through' mode & ought to also record & playback the same channel data as was input.

Answer (score 1):

This should be straightforward in Ableton Live.

- Create a new MIDI track for each instrument.
- In routing options for track:

  - select desired input device
  - select desired input channel for instrument

Are all the tracks you want to record/stream to (shift click lets you arm multiple tracks)

Then start streaming your MIDI in.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what I did - but I did get this to work - I had to set Monitor to In in all midi input track settings

Answer (score 1):

It looks as though this would be a solution to your problem in Logic:

[Logic pro help: Control Multiple Instruments on Different MIDI Channels](http://www.logicprohelp.com/instruments-tracks-midi-channels/)

(haven't tried it as I'm not at home, but looks promising)

Comment: This worked - amazing - totally unobvious place to set things up - thank you very much